# Почему модель "QFileSystemModel" сразу не переходит по указному адресу?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4

Почему не могу перейти сразу на USB-накопитель в `QFileSystemModel` путь указал `/media/usbhd-sdb1/`. А открывается listView с корневого диска.

```
QString mPath = "/media/usbhd-sdb1/";
dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDot | QDir::AllEntries);
dirModel->setRootPath(mPath);
dirModel->sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
ui->listView->setModel(dirModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить строку:

```
ui->listView->setRootIndex(dirModel->index(mPath));
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.